# Error in setting a value to useState variable in function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a button that calls a function when it is pressed. I want to set `startJob = false`. when I added the following code it gives me an error

> TypeError: setJobStart is not a function. (In 'setJobStart(false)', 'setJobStart' is undefined)

**My code**:

```
function App(){
    const [arrived, setArrived ] = useState(false);
    const [startJob, setJobStart ] = useState(false);
 return(
    <ActionButtons />
 )
}

function ActionButtons ({arrived, startJob, dialer, directions}) {
    return(
    <Button title="Arrived" disabled={arrived} onPress={() => ArrivedOk()} buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#0b77b0' }}></Button>
)})
```

**My function** :

```
function ArrivedOk (setJobStart,startJob){
 console.log("OK");
 setJobStart(false);
 // setArrived(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to pass `setJobStart` as an argument to `ArrivedOk` function because it's already defined in :

```
const [startJob, setJobStart ] = useState(false);
```

**Pass `arrived`, `startJob`, `setJobStart`, `dialer`, `directions` as a `prop` to `ActionButtons` component:**

```
function App(){
    const [arrived, setArrived ] = useState(false);
    const [startJob, setJobStart ] = useState(false);
 return(
    <ActionButtons arrived={arrived} startJob={startJob} setJobStart={setJobStart}/> // <--- same for dialer and directions
 )
}
```

**NOTE**: Don't pass `dialer`, `directions` extra props if you're not going to use them inside your component

---

Modify your `ActionButtons` component like this:

```
function ActionButtons ({arrived, startJob, setJobStart, dialer, directions}) {
    return(
    <Button title="Arrived" disabled={arrived} onPress={() => ArrivedOk()} buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#0b77b0' }}></Button>
)})
```

---

Modify your `ArrivedOk` function as below:

And there is no need to pass `startJob` as well because you can get `startJob`'s value directly from the state.

```
function ArrivedOk (startJob){
 console.log("OK");
 setJobStart(false); 
 // setArrived(true);
}
```

Comment: i have updated my code. but now I get an error called `Cant find variable: setJobStart`

Comment: @RyanFonseka Updated my answer please have a look

Comment: Is your `ArrivedOk` function inside your `ActionButtons` component? @RyanFonseka

Comment: yes it is inside the `ActionButtons` component

Comment: `const ArrivedOk = () => {
        console.log(startJob);
        setJobStart(false);
        setArrived(true);
        setDialer(true);
        setDirections(true);
    }` 
updated like above and code worked. Thanks @Sanket